# iTunes redirecting music location to 'localhost'

Tags: external-hard-drive, itunes, localhost

I store my music (thousands of tracks) on an external hard drive, and every so often iTunes adds /localhost/ to the file extension, so it cannot find the original file.

I know I can delete the music from iTunes, and reload it again, but I have already done this twice, and it just happens again, and besides, it takes such a long time.

Can anyone say why this may be happening? Is it something I am doing wrong, perhaps by unplugging the external hard drive when it's not in use?

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: Please provide details of your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, just make sure that the drive letters match. 
When I was adding music from my external drive the letter was F:, but for some reason itunes would change it to E:.

Just change the letter of your drive to match the one that itunes is using and it should work!!